# How to modify the value of a simple type through pointer receiver method in Go?

Tags: pointers, go

I wanted to have a custom type based on a basic type and be able to set its value by calling a pointer receiver.

When I run the following program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type FooInt int
func (fi *FooInt) FromString(i string) {
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(i)
    tmp := FooInt(num)
    fi = &tmp
}

func main() {
    var fi *FooInt
    fi.FromString("5")
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", fi)
}
```

I receive `<nil>`. Why doesn't the pointer declared in `main()` change its value to the address of `tmp`?

Here is a [Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/GbIQm542sI9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All arguments–including the receiver–is a copy inside the function/method. You can only modify the copy.

This applies to pointers too: the receiver value (the `fi` pointer) is a copy, so you can't modify the original pointer, only the copy.

Usually the receiver is a non-`nil` pointer, and you modify the *pointed* value–which results in the original pointed value changed.

In your case you either have to return the pointer and assign the return value:

```
func (fi *FooInt) FromString(i string) *FooInt {
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(i)
    tmp := FooInt(num)
    return &tmp
}

func main() {
    var fi *FooInt
    fi = fi.FromString("5")
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", fi, *fi)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nK4nZuWw8pk)):

```
0xc0000b4020 5
```

Or pass a non-`nil` pointer to what you want to change, in your case it would be of type `**FooInt`

```
func (fi *FooInt) FromString(i string, p **FooInt) {
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(i)
    tmp := FooInt(num)
    *p = &tmp
}

func main() {
    var fi *FooInt
    fi.FromString("5", &fi)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", fi, *fi)
}
```

This outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gUnf2io1uMX).

But easiest would be to just ensure the receiver is not `nil`, so the pointed value can simply be modified:

```
func (fi *FooInt) FromString(i string) {
    num, _ := strconv.Atoi(i)
    *fi = FooInt(num)
}

func main() {
    var fi *FooInt
    fi = new(FooInt)
    fi.FromString("5")
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", fi, *fi)
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Yu3f51qX3Lz).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation, that makes total sense. I was able to patch the code which I was working on just like I intended to.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax:

```
func (fi *FooInt) FromString(i string) {
    // ...
}
```

is partly [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for:

```
func FromString(fi *fooInt, i string) {
    // ...
}
```

That is, the `fi` parameter here is an ordinary local variable.  If you assign *to* it, you replace the pointer value that the caller supplied, rather than writing through the pointer value that the caller supplied.  Hence you need to use:

```
    *fi = FooInt(num)
```

in the body of the function.  However, now the caller *must pass a non-nil pointer:*

```
var fi FooInt
fi.FromString("5")
```

for instance.

[Here is a complete example](https://play.golang.org/p/0bfJfvTekxy), including a method by which you can call the `FromString` function and pass an explicit pointer.

(I say *partly* syntactic sugar because this defines `FromString` as a *receiver function* or *method*, which can only be done using this syntax.  So the syntax is required—it's not an alternative to some other syntax, as people sometimes mean when using the phrase "syntactic sugar".)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a hard time deciding which to accept.