# Reference values not being updated

Tags: go, pointers

I am new to the Golang world & trying to implement a BST in Golang. But while inserting/updating pointers values are not getting updated/inserted. For example in the following code the output is:

```
3
[]
```

my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var inOrderTrace []int = []int{}

type node struct {
    value      int
    leftChild  *node
    rightChild *node
}

type tree struct {
    root *node
    len  int
}

func (myTree tree) inOrderTraverse(node *node) {
    if node == nil {
        return
    }
    myTree.inOrderTraverse(node.leftChild)
    inOrderTrace = append(inOrderTrace, node.value)
    myTree.inOrderTraverse(node.rightChild)
}

func (myTree *tree) insertNode(nodeToManipulate *node, toInsert int) {
    if nodeToManipulate == nil {
        nodeToManipulate = &node{toInsert, nil, nil}
        myTree.len++
        return
    }
    if nodeToManipulate.value > toInsert {
        myTree.insertNode(nodeToManipulate.leftChild, toInsert)
    } else {
        myTree.insertNode(nodeToManipulate.rightChild, toInsert)
    }
}

func main() {
    myTree := &tree{nil, 0}
    var elements []int = []int{1, 0, 2}
    for _, element := range elements {
        myTree.insertNode(myTree.root, element)
    }
    myTree.inOrderTraverse(myTree.root)
    fmt.Println(myTree.len)
    fmt.Println(inOrderTrace)
}
```

I am expecting the inserted values to be printed.Thanks.

Comment: To update the value to which a pointer points you need to use pointer indirection. And btw. to be able to do that, the pointer needs to be non-nil, else you crash your program. E.g. given a *non-nil* `p` of type `*node`, you'd need to do `*p = node{...}` to update what `p` points to. So, in case it's not clear, this `nodeToManipulate = &node{toInsert, nil, nil}` is useless, it does not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but helpful and important: There are no references in Go and a pointer is not a reference. It's worth using the proper language and not trying to use half-invalid concepts (like references) from other languages. The name of the language is Go.

Answer (score 2):

`insertNode()` has a parameter of pointer type (`nodeToManipulate *node`). Inside `insertNode()`:

```
nodeToManipulate = &node{toInsert, nil, nil}
```

This line will just assign a pointer to the parameter, a local variable. Calling this method from `main()`, and passing `myTree.root`, the `myTree.root` will never be modified, as written above, only the function parameter (which is a copy, a local variable). This means your tree never gets built, the root of tree never gets modified.

To modify something, you have to pass a pointer to it, and modify the *pointed* value.

For example:

```
func (myTree *tree) insertNode(pnodeToManipulate **node, toInsert int) {
    if *pnodeToManipulate == nil {
        *pnodeToManipulate = &node{toInsert, nil, nil}
        myTree.len++
        return
    }
    nodeToManipulate := *pnodeToManipulate
    if nodeToManipulate.value > toInsert {
        myTree.insertNode(&nodeToManipulate.leftChild, toInsert)
    } else {
        myTree.insertNode(&nodeToManipulate.rightChild, toInsert)
    }
}

func main() {
    myTree := &tree{nil, 0}
    var elements []int = []int{1, 0, 2}
    for _, element := range elements {
        myTree.insertNode(&myTree.root, element)
    }
    myTree.inOrderTraverse(myTree.root)
    fmt.Println(myTree.len)
    fmt.Println(inOrderTrace)
}
```

With this change output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/NoU7le1ne2G)):

```
3
[0 1 2]
```

If you don't like double pointers (`**`), another option is to return the new value and assign it at the caller.

See related / possible duplicates:

[Can the pointer in a struct pointer method be reassigned to another instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421495/can-the-pointer-in-a-struct-pointer-method-be-reassigned-to-another-instance/35426997#35426997)

[How to modify the value of a simple type through pointer receiver method in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761945/how-to-modify-the-value-of-a-simple-type-through-pointer-receiver-method-in-go/61762145#61762145)

[What use case does pointers to pointer (eg **int) have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288751/what-use-case-does-pointers-to-pointer-eg-int-have/45297016#45297016)